# c++- variables to system()

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on a console program for Windows, and one of my settings is an option to change the console and text color. 
    
I am using c++, so I can do something like `system("color 07");`, which will make the background black and the text white. 
    
What I want to do is to present all 16 color options, and then let the user take his pick. 
    
(Below is a portion of my code):

```
int a;
int b;
cout << "Please enter your background color." << endl;
cin >> a;   //the user inputs 0
cout << "Please enter your text color." << endl;
cin >> b;     //the user inputs 7
```

How to I pass the two variables to the system() call? I googled around, but all I could find were string to system(), which I do not want.
    
    
Also, I am very well aware of how evil system() is, so if anyone has other options other than system() that will do the same thing, that would be fine. But please do not tell me how evil system() is.
    
    
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a simpler solution using C++ constructs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string bgClr,fgClr;
    cin >> bgClr >> fgClr;

    ::system((bgClr+fgClr).c_str());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `system` command takes a single `const char*` parameter. Therefore you just need to build a string for the command you wish to execute.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int backgroundColor;
    std::cout << "Enter background color\n";
    std::cin >> backgroundColor;

    int foregroundColor;
    std::cout << "Enter foreground color\n";
    std::cin >> foregroundColor;

    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "color " << backgroundColor << foregroundColor;
    std::cout << "Command to execute: '" << stream.str() << "'\n";

    ::system(stream.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a good sol. But @James Adkison : do you think we can't take inputs as string themselves ?

Comment: Are you asking if the two color variables can be of type `std::string`?

Comment: @SameerSawla Yes, I know you can use `std::string` **however** the `color` command appears to take numeric inputs therefore it is more correct to collect numeric inputs from the user (i.e., a `std::string` would allow a user to enter non-numeric values). Furthermore, a robust solution would consider the valid input for the `color` command and verify/notify the user when invalid numeric input.is provided.

Comment: Yep that is justified.

Answer (score -1):

```
char command[500] = "";
sprintf(command, "color(%d, %d)", a, b);
int result = system(command);
```

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: This is a C solution (assuming appropriate header file #include'd).  C++ provides safer alternatives.

Comment: As he is using the system call, it is a reasonable approach for a newbie.  Drowning them in std::string and the c_ptr function works, but is too high a level of detail.   system takes a char *.   KISS.

Comment: I haven't drowned anyone.   I simply pointed out there are safer alternatives.  KISS is not a reason to shy away from comments about possibility of better technique.